# SSRS Expression inversed return

Tags: date, reporting-services

So I have an expression that calculates the number of weekdays between two dates (excluding these dates). But the expression seems to give the opposite results of what I want and I don't know why. Here's the expression:

```
 =iif(IsNothing(Fields!End_Date.Value) or IsNothing(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value) or Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value>Fields!End_Date.Value,"Invalid Data",
(DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Fields!End_Date.Value,Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value)+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!End_Date.Value,Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value)*2) 
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!End_Date.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!End_Date.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value,1) = 7,1,0)-2)
```

So, the result I get from this expression is that every situation where the End Date is smaller than the Report Submitted Date I get the text `Invalid Data` and the rest are `#Error` or negative numbers.

Now I know I can solve this by switching the `True` and `False` clause but I would like to understand why these results are switched because for as far as I can read:

IF End Date OR Report Submitted Date are null
OR IF End Date is bigger than Report Submitted Date I should get the `Invalid Data` text.

Any answers are appreciated.

EDIT 1:

So I have changed the expression from an IIF to a switch.

```
=switch(
IsNothing(Fields!End_Date.Value),"Invalid Data",
IsNothing(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value),"Invalid Data",
Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value <= Fields!End_Date.Value, "Invalid Data",
True, "Good Data"
)
```

And this gives me the results that I expect, however, if I change `Good Data` with my expression to calculate the difference of weekdays between the two dates I still get a `#Error`. It looks like when I do this it doesn't recognize the `Report Submitted Date` as `Nothing`. Altered expression below:

```
=switch(
IsNothing(Fields!End_Date.Value),"Invalid Data",
IsNothing(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value),"Invalid Data",
Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value <= Fields!End_Date.Value, "Invalid Data",
True, ((DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Fields!End_Date.Value,Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value)+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!End_Date.Value,Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value)*2) 
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!End_Date.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!End_Date.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value,1) = 7,1,0)-2)
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You have your dates switched in the DateDiff - the EndDate should be the second date (the third argument). That only fixes the negatives though. I don't see why you're getting an ERROR except for bad data (not valid dates). Check the error list for some details. You can also look at your data for the rows that you're getting an error.

Comment: @HannoverFist The EndDate is supposed to be before the ReportSubmittedDate. The report that is submitted is a summary of the event from the EndDate so the dates may look switched but actually aren't. OR is it in a specific part of the expression that I switched them?

Comment: No - I was thinking the end date was in the wrong space. Try putting the IIF statement for the ISNOTHING on the outside of the SWITCH. =IIF IsNothing(Fields!End_Date.Value),"Invalid Data",
IsNothing(Fields!Report_Submitted_Date.Value),"Invalid Data", SWITCH(...